MinIO failed to make multipart upload
I faced with an issue trying to upload file more then 5MB. I have my service and MinIO inside the Kubernetes cluster. I use latest Java MinIO client version and image
quay.io/minio/minio:RELEASE.2023-05-27T05-56-19Z

MinIO client configuration
public class MinioConfig {
    @Value("${minio.access.accessKey}")
    String accessKey;

    @Value("${minio.access.secret}")
    String accessSecret;

    @Value("${minio.access.url}")
    String minioUrl;

    @Bean
    public MinioClient generateMinioClient() {
        try {
            OkHttpClient httpClient =
                    new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .build();
            MinioClient client =
                    MinioClient.builder()
                            .endpoint(minioUrl)
                            .httpClient(httpClient)
                            .credentials(accessKey, accessSecret)
                            .build();
            client.ignoreCertCheck();
            return client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Code where call appears. I already tried minioClient.uploadeObject() but errors is the same.
Debugging with purpose to identify is file present
var stream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            log.info("File to upload {}, with size {}", file.getPath(), file.length());
            log.info("Stream {}, availability {}", stream, stream.available());
            var args =
                    PutObjectArgs.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName)
                            .object(folderPath + fileName(fileId))
                            .stream(stream, file.length(), -1)
                            .build();
            log.info("Uploaded object {}", args);

            var response = minioClient.putObject(args);

I got an error 400 and response null
MinIO audit logs shows

So file is reaching the destination and it's uploading but got an error on the final part of upload. Connecting locally to the MinIO in cluster everything works fine. Environment has up-to date version with debug logs
Define what could be a problem of multipart upload
